# HTML/CSS table: align "sub-rows" over columns

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to display my data (from elasticsearch) in a web page in a table (ideally in the end with datatables). In the table there should be 1 row for each id / document. However the document contains array fields (columns). Say I have 2 columns which are related and each array in the column has 5 elements, I want that the each of the 5 elements is aligned over the 2 columns taking into account that in 1 column it's a long text and in the other just a number.

See below for an example:

```
id|col1   |col2
---------------------------
  |-el1   |-long text over
 1|       | multiple rows
  |-el2   |-text2
```

The data is available as list of python dicts were entry for col1 would be a list again.

How can I achieve this ( ideally without nested tables) if possible at all?

Comment: `rowspan` seems indicated here

Answer (score -1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  width: 80%;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  word-break: break-all;
  text-align: center;
}

.number-td {
  width: 20%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50">
      1
    </td>
    <td class="number-td">
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      Text 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50">
      2
    </td>
    <td class="number-td">
      2
    </td>
    <td>
      Text 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50">
      3
    </td>
    <td class="number-td">
      3
    </td>
    <td>
      Text 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50">
      4
    </td>
    <td class="number-td">
      4
    </td>
    <td>
      Text 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50">
      5
    </td>
    <td class="number-td">
      5
    </td>
    <td>
      Text 5
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have kept width="50" on ID column and on number column I have kept width:20%. You can keep both or customize as you like! Hope the solution will be helpful for you